# Как в sql сравнить две строки без учета  знаков препинания?

Tags: php, sql

В условии where необходимо сравнить две строки, чтобы условие равенства выполнялось без учета знаков препинания, т.е. didn't или didnt или didnt.

надо этот запрос переделать, чтобы он сравнивал `$_POST["name"]` и поле `textUS`, без учета знаков препинания 
`mysql_query('SELECT * FROM les WHERE textUS= "'.$_POST["name"].'"',$conn);`

Answer (score 3):

Наверное можно как-то так (нужные знаки как добавить думаю догадаетесь):

```
where LOWER(REPLACE('yourstr',"'","")) = LOWER(REPLACE(field,"'",""))
```

Comment: а 2 строка куда вписывать?можно подробнее

Comment: Эм... Вам надо php кодом сравнивать или php? Если php почитайте поисковик по запросу "работа со строками php". Можете ещё почитать про регэкспы. Общая идея то простая - вам надо нормализовать две строки, так чтобы исключить разность.

Comment: Вы тут багтрекер завели? :-) сделайте выводы о значениях 'yourstr' и field...